# передний и задний фон в Swing java

Tags: java, swing

Пишу игру с использованием Swing: создал класс `Background`, в котором для своего окна (класс, унаследованный от `JPanel`) задаю изображение, также я хочу задать пару кнопок, но изображение перекрывает их.

Каким образом можно добиться того,чтобы кнопки были на переднем плане? Если создать несколько экземпляров класса панели, и в одном, например, поместить картинку-фоновое изображение, а в другом поместить кнопки, и в итоге поместить это все в класс унаследованный от `JFrame`, и первой прогружать панель с картинкой,а второй с кнопками,то это прокатит или есть более адекватные способы?

Comment: можете злоупотребить тем, что любой swing-компонент, включая `JLabel` является контейнером, в который можно установить layout и накидать компонентов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать контейнер Layered Panes. При добавление объекта GUI в контейнер указывается целое число, которое определяет глубину. Чем выше число, тем выше располагается объект в контейнере.

```
layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(i));
```

Также там есть такие полезные функции как:

```
layeredPane.moveToFront(label); // Передвигает объект наверх (нулевая позиция)
layeredPane.moveToBack(label); // Передвигает объект вниз
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ,нашел еще ссылку по этой теме,может кому-то поможет:http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-gui-javafx/thread655600.html